# Answer value increment for quiz webpage java script error

Tags: javascript, html

I have four questions here as quiz, correct anwer for the question 1) 1 , 2)  11, 3) 2root2, 4) 1/root3

When i give correct answers the output result shows only 2 even if i do all four options correct. i have problem with question 2 and question 3. I guess the problem is with JS.

https://jsfiddle.net/harrybabu93/s5a7qvdr/5/

```js
function check() {
    var c = 0;
    var q1 = document.quiz.question1.value;
    var q2 = document.quiz.question2.value;
    var q3 = document.quiz.question3.value;
    var q4 = document.quiz.question4.value;
    var q5 = document.quiz.question5.value;
    var q6 = document.quiz.question6.value;
    var q7 = document.quiz.question7.value;
    var q8 = document.quiz.question8.value;
    var q9 = document.quiz.question9.value;
    var q10 = document.quiz.question10.value;
    var q11 = document.quiz.question11.value;
    var q12 = document.quiz.question12.value;
    var q13 = document.quiz.question13.value;
    var q14 = document.quiz.question14.value;
    var q15 = document.quiz.question15.value;

    if (q1 == "1") {
        c++
    }
    
    if (q2 == "11") {
        c++
    }
    
    if (q3 == "code1") {
        c++
    }
    if (q4 == "code2") {
        c++
    }



    window.alert(c);

}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

strong{
    line-height: 25px;
}

.mark {
    float: right
}

form[name=quiz] {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

ol {
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-position: inside;
}

ol li {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 2px 0px rgb(91, 91, 91);
}

li table {
    width: 100%;
}

li table td {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

li table td:first-child {
    width: 70%;
}

td p {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

td button {

    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    color: #fff;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
    background-color: #f44336;
    width: 80px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
    background-color: red;
}


td a {
    margin: 5px;

}

h1 {
    padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quiz Frame Work</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Try%201.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Try%201.js"></script>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
    <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
    

</head>

<body>
   
    <form name="quiz" id="quiz">
       <h1>Title</h1>
        <ol>

            <!-- Question1 -->
            <li>
                <strong>The value of \(\frac{1}{{{{\log }_4}120}} + \frac{1}{{{{\log }_5}120}} + \frac{1}{{{{\log }_6}120}}\) is</strong>
                <i class="mark">Mark:1</i><br><br>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question1" id="question1" value="0">
                                <label for="question1">0</label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question1" id="question2" value="1">
                                <label for="question2">1</label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question1" id="question3" value="24">
                                <label for="question3">24</label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question1" id="question4" value="120">
                                <label for="question4">120</label>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           
                            <a href="https://youtu.be/8E6yC6zgGVY" target="_blank">English  <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i></a>
                            <a href="https://youtu.be/7-sE2-ZIz44" target="_blank">Tamil  <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i></a>                   
                            <a href="https://youtu.be/7-sE2-ZIz44" target="_blank">Notes  <i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i></a> 
                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>

            <!-- Question2 -->
            <li>
                <strong>For a 3x3 matrix A, |A| = 4 and adj A = \(\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}1&p&3\\1&3&3\\2&4&4\end{array}} \right)\), then the value of p is</strong>
                <i class="mark">Mark:1</i><br><br>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question2" id="question1" value="0">
                                <label for="question1">4</label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question2" id="question2" value="1">
                                <label for="question2">11</label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question2" id="question3" value="24">
                                <label for="question3">5</label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question2" id="question4" value="120">
                                <label for="question4">0</label>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="https://youtu.be/u5qbsXyyOic" target="_blank">English  <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i></a>
                            <a href="https://youtu.be/7-sE2-ZIz44" target="_blank">Tamil  <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i></a>                   
                            <a href="https://youtu.be/7-sE2-ZIz44" target="_blank">Notes  <i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
            
            
            <!-- Question3 -->
            <li>
                <strong>A plane P which is perpendicular to two planes 2x-2y+z = 0 & x-y+2z = 4, passes through (1,-2,1) . The distance of the plane P from the point Q (1,2,2) is</strong>
                <i class="mark">Mark:1</i><br><br>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question3" id="question1" value="0">
                                <label for="question1">0</label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question3" id="question2" value="1">
                                <label for="question2">1</label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question3" id="question3" value="24">
                                <label for="question3">\(\sqrt 2 \)</label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question3" id="question4" value="code1">
                                <label for="question4">\(2\sqrt 2 \)</label>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="https://youtu.be/o8LAvq6xxvc" target="_blank">English  <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i></a>
                            <a href="https://youtu.be/7-sE2-ZIz44" target="_blank">Tamil  <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i></a>                   
                            <a href="https://youtu.be/7-sE2-ZIz44" target="_blank">Notes  <i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
            
            
            <!-- Question4 -->
            <li>
                <strong>The area enclosed between the curves x = \(a{y^2}\)and y = \(a{x^2}\), a > 0 is 1sq. unit, then the value of ‘a’ is</strong>
                <i class="mark">Mark:1</i><br><br>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question4" id="question1" value="code1">
                                <label for="question1">\(\frac{1}{{\sqrt 3 }}\)</label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question4" id="question2" value="\(\frac{1}{3}\) ">
                                <label for="question2">\(\frac{1}{3}\) </label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question4" id="question3" value="\(\sqrt 3 \) ">
                                <label for="question3">\(\sqrt 3 \) </label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="question4" id="question4" value="3">
                                <label for="question4">3</label>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="https://youtu.be/1sTZT2d0bq0" target="_blank">English  <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i></a>
                            <a href="https://youtu.be/7-sE2-ZIz44" target="_blank">Tamil  <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i></a>                   
                            <a href="https://youtu.be/7-sE2-ZIz44" target="_blank">Notes  <i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
            
           

        </ol>

        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Show my score" onclick="check()">
    </form>

 <input type="button" name="submit" value="Show my score" onclick="check()">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: java != javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your script is checking for the wrong values in your quiz:

```js
if (q3 == "o4") {
    c++
}
if (q4 == "c2") {
    c++
}
```

`o4` and `c2` aren't options in your quiz, and hence the correct answer doesn't get counted. You instead need to check for the correct option in those questions. For example, if q3 had correct answer \sqrt{2} and q4 had correct answer (\frac{1}{3}) then you need to change the JS to:

```js
if (q3 == "\(\sqrt 2 \)") {
    c++
}
if (q4 == "\(\frac{1}{3}\)") {
    c++
}
```

Comment: If i add this my button is not working for alert , and also i have given same value in HTML and JS if you check ... check my jsfiddle link

Comment: Kindly check this, if i choose correct answer for question 1 alone and submit, it shows value 1 in alert, if i choose correct answer for question 2 alone and submit, it shows value 1 in alert, but is choose correct answer for both Q1 and Q2 it must show two in alert but it still shows one, any problem with c++ increment ?